# No metadata classes to process when using doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am following tutorial from this link: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/getting-started.html
But I always end up with `[OK] No Metadata Classes to process.`

Tried add `null, null, false` to config in `boostrap.php`. Also tried `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` and added `ORM\`.

When I changed to use XML, it said

> `In MappingException.php line 93: Class 'product' does not exist`

Just simple php mvc project with doctrine, no symfony, no zend (Most results I searched on Google are about them).

Comment: Could use just a tiny bit more information.  Maybe update your question with src/Product.php code to start.

Comment: Here is an example of the [Doctrine getting started](https://github.com/cerad/d26-getting_started) code.  Both annotations and xml mappings are implemented.